# Calculating a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

From some reasons (trying to solve the  cubic equation $11925\,{z}^{3}-1219\,{z}^{2}-19186\,z+360=0$ with  positive discriminant)  I know that the number 
$$
 a=\sqrt [3]{201401326+12825\,i\sqrt {250532652963}}+\sqrt [3]{201401326-
12825\,i\sqrt {250532652963}}
$$
is a real number.

How to calculate the real number?

I was tried manipulate with $a, a^2, a^3, \ldots, a^6$ but  no good results. Any ideas?

Comment: I plugged this into a calculator and got the imaginary number 3238.805736+1825.047214i.

Comment: I down voted for "reasons", not a very helpful explanation, is it? Cubic roots are inherently multivalued specify which one you are talking about and express the root as a real number if already know that it is a real number, as you say. Then we can help you find the cubic root.

Comment: Can you share with us the "some reasons"  that you know this is a real number?

Comment: some resons  - I have a cubic equation with positive discriminant, so it has a real roots.

Comment: @RK01 Looks like the sum of a complex number and its conjugate.  Looks perfectly real as long as you take the branch cut somewhere near the negative real axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not possible unless your numbers are the cubes of items in essentially the same quadratic field.... This is the **Casus Irreducibilis**.

Andre's suggestion is **Casus Irritus**,  which appears to be genuine Latin and means nothing can be done. I suggest **Casus Irritabilious** which I made up.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis

> If D > 0, then there are three distinct real roots. Either a rational
>   root exists and can be found using the rational root test, in which
>   case the cubic polynomial can be factored into the product of a linear
>   polynomial and a quadratic polynomial, the latter of which can be
>   solved via the quadratic formula; or no such factorization can occur,
>   so the polynomial is casus irreducibilis: all roots are real, but
>   require complex numbers to express them in radicals.

Where was I: if a cubic with integer coefficients has three **real but irrational** roots, then these cannot be recovered in any better manner than what you already have.

All very circular: trying to find the real and imaginary parts of a cube root of a complex number leads to two cubic equations, each with three irrational roots. Frustrating.

From comment below:

```
PARI/GP is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and comes WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY WHATSOEVER.

? q = 11925 * x^3 - 1219 * x^2 - 19186 * x + 360 
%1 = 11925*x^3 - 1219*x^2 - 19186*x + 360
? factor(q)
%2 = 
[11925*x^3 - 1219*x^2 - 19186*x + 360 1]

? polroots(q)
%3 = [-1.227984336137049661723863057, 0.01874544997631179824408880833, 1.311461108382960085701996471]~
?
```

Comment: Yes, have a cubic equation with positive discriminant.

Comment: @Leox, does it have any rational root?

Comment: No, Maple find the roots but they all are very complicated expression like as I wrote above

Comment: @Leox, ask it to factor the polynomial. For a cubic, there is a nontrivial factor of the polynomial if and only if there is a rational root.

Comment: It should be called the *Casus Irritus.*

Comment: @Andre, Casus Irritabilious

Comment: There is a trigonometric solution, though.

Comment: hmmm, don't know Latin, http://www.eudict.com/?lang=lateng&word=irritus

Comment: The  polynomial is $11925\,{z}^{3}-1219\,{z}^{2}-19186\,z+360$. Maple cant factorise it.

Comment: @WillJagy: I had five high school years of Latin.  Of limited use, perhaps, but a lot more interesting than high school math.

Comment: I knew someone who took school Latin, they had a class motto, Semper Ubi Sub Ubi.; meaning Always Wear UnderWear